# "this" reference when using jQuery trigger, triggerHandler, or simulate

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, eventtrigger

Our css guys have an icon overlaying an image thumbnail for a video.  When the user clicks the thumbnail, the video should play (and it does!), but when they click the overlaying "play" image, that image consumes the click and it's not directly passed to the underlying image.

So I searched and found the trigger() function of jQuery and added it to the icon click handler to trigger the thumbnail handler and it works fine EXCEPT that when thumbnail click is run, the "this" reference is for the icon, not the corresponding thumbnail.

I've tried triggerHandler() and jQuery's internal simulate() functions and it's all the same.

In the event handler I need the id of the actual thumbnail and not the overlay icon.

Is there anyway to have an overlaying image ignore the click and just let it bubble up (or down) to something else in the z-order?  Or even simply fire them both?

Comment: Code? HTML? Anything?

Comment: you have 400 pts, you know better than to ask questions like this without posting code.

Comment: Show teh codez you have tried

Comment: Yes, as a veteran user I know when code needs to be posted and in this case, none is actually needed.  All the code is in the description.  I'm not going to share actual work product (good practice), so I'd have to rewrite dummy code to demonstrate what was already clear in the question.

If there was a chance that my code was the actual issue vs. a general discussion of how to do something that step would have been necessary.  But in this case Eduard Void understood and successfully answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return true; in parent event (overlaying "play" image) will continue to the child event (thumbnail)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much for actually reading the question and answering it so fast!  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css click through, using pointer events none css `pointer-events: none`. This does not work for IE10 and below, but you could use this polyfill:

https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill